# anaconda3 not getting deleted even after uninstalling Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.8, anaconda3

even after uninstalling anaconda,I have anaconda3 file , its keeps coming into my files even after deleting it. How to delete it permanently as all my pip installed libraries are stored in this anaconda3 folder.

I even removed all that paths related to anaconda from my environment variables,Can anyone help me here to completely delete this anaconda3 folder or atleast tell me a way to change the location, where all my pip libraries are to be installed